# Knockout changing data-bind based on user selection

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-binding, knockout.js

I have some knockout code that consists of a list object and item object. There could be multiple lists and each list has an array of objects. I made this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Td5Nc/) to demonstrate what I am trying to explain. What I want to be able to do is have a select box where the user can select a list and then the items from that list will be loaded. Currently I have my data-bind set up like this `data-bind="foreach: lists[0].items"`. The index of the list is hard codded into the bind. Is there some way that I could dynamically assign the index of the list I wish to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put an observable instead of `0`:

```
data-bind="foreach: lists[selectedIndex()].items"
```

With `selectedIndex`: `self.selectedIndex = ko.observable(0);`

Comment: Do I need to define `self.selectedIndex = ko.observable(0);` in the view model or in the list object?

Comment: At the same level as `lists`